# check whether the ROBDD diagram is correct

Tags: data-structures, bdd, binary-decision-diagram

Here below I have shown a BDD and its ROBDD. Can someone please let me know whether the drawn diagram is correct. If not please let me know the mistake that I have done.

BDD

[image]

Answer - ROBDD

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider valuation `0100`: it leads to `1` in the first diagram and to `0` in the second.

[image]